# How to inject a new object every time it's needed?

Tags: structuremap

I have this constructor:

```
public GroupController(IUserService userService, IGroupService groupService)
{
    _groupService = groupService;
    _userService = userService;
}
```

userService and groupService has the same object in constructor:

```
public UserService(IDb db)
{
     _db = db;
}

public GroupService(IDb db)
{
     _db = db;
}
```

and my container is this:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.Scan(scan =>
    {
        scan.TheCallingAssembly();
        scan.WithDefaultConventions();
    });

    x.For<IDb>().Use<Db>();
    x.For<IUserService>().Use<UserService>();
    x.For<IGroupService>().Use<GroupService>();
});
```

So, How can I inject an IDb for UserService and an another IDb for GroupService because I can't use the same instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default lifecycle for StructureMap objects is `PerRequestLifecycle`, which means that multiple requests for the same interface within the same build session will resolve to a single instance. If you want it to resolve each interface request to a unique instance, you can use the `UniquePerRequestLifecycle`.

**TL;DR**: Configure your `IDb` like this:

```
x.For<IDb>.AlwaysUnique().Use<Db>();
```